# How to parse NSData from Login Items property file (com.apple.loginitems.plist)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I need to get alias/path of applications for every user which are running at login.

Each user has own com.apple.loginitems.plist in /Users/username/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist

There is a property called "Alias" with NSData type I assume it's a path of application which OS going to start at login.

```
<00000000 009e0003 00010000 cd886743 0000482b 00000000 0102fad2 0105e933 0000cbcd ed3f0000 00000920 fffe0000 00000000 0000ffff ffff0001 00040102 fad2000e 001a000c 004d0065 00730073 00610067 00650073 002e0061 00700070 000f0012 0008006d 00610063 004f0053 00780020 00320012 00194170 706c6963 6174696f 6e732f4d 65737361 6765732e 61707000 00130001 2f00ffff 0000>
```

Also the is another property called "com.apple.LSSharedFileList.Binding" which could be a path:

```
<646e6962 00000000 01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 05000000 00000000 706c6973 743f3f3f 3f000000 00000000 00>
```

How to parse it?

Please note that I run my application under root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but I'll give an answer in case someone like me is still interested.

Swift 2:

```
func getFileURLFromAliasData(aliasData: NSData) -> NSURL? {
    let aliasCF = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer<UInt8>(aliasData.bytes), aliasData.length)
    if aliasCF == nil {
        print("Unable to create CFData from NSData")
        return nil
    }
    let bookmark = CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromAliasRecord(kCFAllocatorDefault, aliasCF)
    if bookmark == nil {
        print("Unable to create CFData for bookmark from CFData")
        return nil
    }
    let bookmarkManaged = bookmark.takeRetainedValue()
    let url = CFURLCreateByResolvingBookmarkData(kCFAllocatorDefault, bookmarkManaged, [], nil, nil, nil, nil)
    if url == nil {
        print("Unable to create CFURL from CFData for bookmark")
        return nil
    }
    let urlManaged = url.takeRetainedValue()
    let filePath = CFURLGetString(urlManaged) as NSString
    let nsURL = NSURL(string: filePath as String)
    return nsURL
}
```

There's more to look for in this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/pull/762/files). I've actually reproduced and shortened that code.

I haven't had to do that in Objective-C which is marked for the question, but it shouldn't be very difficult to rewrite the Swift code. This [changeset](http://www.growl.info/hg/growl/rev/72ed8c52b4b5) may also be of some help in this regard.